# Examples of matter modeling in fiction

Tags: reference-request, history

Can you remember any example of a work of fiction, for example, movie, book, short story, anime, et cetera, where computational matter modeling was an important plot device? I'm looking for examples were it was portrayed realistically (i.e. [hard science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_science_fiction) examples would be best).

Comment: Although it is not a science fiction movie, I remember the example of the "Brave" movie, which is a children's movie in which there is a main character named Merida with long red curly hair. Her hair is one of the items that draws the most attention and it took a lot of computer simulation to make it as realistic as possible.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález, that would be a example of modeling applied to film making. I was thinking more in line with matter modeling being part of the story being told. Some science fields are very represented in fiction, for example, Astrophysics, or Genetic Engineering. I think ours is a bit underrepresented.

Comment: I see no reason to close this. In fact I was even going to answer it. It's not a "how do I calculate this?" question, but it is still a question, and does not violate any rule, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It is true that the answer by @CarmenGonzález is not about the plot, but I think that could make for another interesting question: "Examples of matter modelling for making movies"

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page related to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materials_science_in_science_fiction

Comment: When I first read this, I was reminded of when my friend was contacted by someone from Marvel Studios, asking for his permission to use a formula sheet that he put on his website and was full of complicated-looking equations, for their next film, which turned out to be Iron Man II. There is a scene where Iron Man opens a notebook and you can see Maxwell's equations written on the pages. However now I see that you want an example where "computational" matter modeling was actually an "important" part of the plot. This is even harder because you say you want it to be hard science fiction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Last Question by Isaac Asimov is a short story where a computer is tasked with solving the problem of entropy.

It's a brilliant story and definitely worth listening to and reading

https://youtu.be/ojEq-tTjcc0

Comment: Great post! I completely forgot this existed. I remember reading it as a kid and being blown away.